# How can I access Property Owner Details in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django View where all users (Landlord, Agent and prospect) can access and on this view, I want to display the name of the property owner on my template but I am only getting None displayed whenever a Prospect user is on the view. Understand that the three users have their Models with a OneToOneField relationship with the User Model. And I also have a Profile Model with the same relationship with the User Model.
See the view code below:

```
def property_detail(request, property_id):
user = request.user
#Check if user is authenticated
if user.is_authenticated:
    #Check if user is Landlord
    if hasattr(user, 'landlord'):
        properties = Property.objects.filter(landlord=user.landlord).prefetch_related('agent').order_by('-last_updated')[:4]
        property_owner = user.landlord.profile if hasattr(user.landlord, 'profile') else None
    #Check if user is Agent
    elif hasattr(user, 'agent'):
        properties = Property.objects.filter(agent=user.agent).prefetch_related('landlord').order_by('-last_updated')[:4]
        property_owner = user.agent.profile if hasattr(user.agent, 'profile') else None
    else:
        properties = Property.objects.order_by('-last_updated')[:4]
        property_owner = None

    

    #Get the Property by its Product key from DB
    property_instance = get_object_or_404(Property, pk=property_id)

    #Send Notification to property owner
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                content = form.cleaned_data['content']
                subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
                Message.objects.create(property=property_instance, sender=user, recipient=property_owner, subject=subject, content=content)
                messages.success(request, 'Notification sent successfully with your Contact Details.')

    else:
        form = MessageForm()
        
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'properties':properties,
        'property_owner': property_owner,
        'page_title': 'Property Detail',
        'property': property_instance,
    }
    return render(request, 'realestate/landlord_agent_property.html', context)
 # Handle the case when the user is not authenticated
logout(request)
messages.warning(request, 'Session expired. Please log in again.')
return redirect(reverse('account-login'))
```

Comment: Just find my answer might not be what you’re asking for. You explicitly set `property_owner` to `None` when a prospect user views. You need to change this part if prospect user is expected to view info of property owner.

Answer (score 1):

First, I must say that your database design approach is quite confusing, You could have used just one model `Profile` with flags (e.g. `is_landlord`, `is_agent` and `is_propect`). Or, even better, make use of the [`Groups`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#groups).

Based on what you described about your `Models`, the issue here, is that you are trying to access unexistent attributes, so it always return `None`:

```py
property_owner = user.agent.profile if hasattr(user.agent, 'profile') else None
```

An `User` has a `Profile` and can be an `Agent`, but they are distinct attributes. Meaning that `Profile` is not inside `Agent`:

```py
property_owner = user.profile if hasattr(user, 'profile') else None
```

And, in template to display the name:

```py
{% if property_owner %}
    <p>{{property_owner.user.get_full_name}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The reason why I couldn't include is_landland or is_agent flag as Profile Model properties is that, upon user registration, the user type needs to be identified or selected in order to know who he or she is and also for Database optimisation. And on the other hand, the property_owner variable for getting the logged in user, understand that this view is not limited to the Landlord and Agent user alone but also to the Prospect user as well so the else statement comes into play whenever a Prospect user logs in and therefore it is not possible to get the details of the property owner.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use `hasattr` to identify user group. A user will always have an attribute of `landlord`, despite being `None` or a model instance.

Use `user.landlord is not None` instead.